# Checking if an image format is Lossless in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, lossless-compression

I am working on an application that requires images submitted to it to be lossless. Currently I am opening the image with PIL and checking if the "format" attribute is a lossless format. This requires me to manually keep a list of formats, and I have no idea if, for instance, a jpeg that was submitted just happens to have the lossless variant applied.

```
import PIL
import PIL.Image


def validate_image(path):
    img = PIL.Image.open(path)
    if not img.format.lower() in ['bmp', 'gif', 'png', ...]:
        raise Exception("File %s has invalid image format %s" % (path, img.format))
```

Is there a better way to check if the image file is lossless?

Comment: Do you have to use PIL? For example, with PythonMagick, I'm pretty sure you can check the `CompressionType` attribute. And that's a much easier test—the only native compression type that's lossy is `JPEGCompression` (used by lossy JPEG and TIFF files); for non-native compressions you will get `UndefinedCompression`, but you can just assume that always means lossy.

Comment: As you point out, your code doesn't even work, because a lossless JPEG is still a `'jpeg'`, and both lossy and lossless TIFFs are `'tiff'`. But let's take a step back… How does your application handle submitted images? Does it handle lossless JPEG? For that matter, does it handle any types that PIL (or ImageMagick, etc.) doesn't, or not handle any types that PIL (etc.) does? Because, if so, just checking for "lossless" isn't sufficient anyway.

Comment: In other words: Why does your app need lossless images? If it will throw an exception (or the equivalent in C or Java or whatever?) when given a lossy image, that's fine; just put the same code (or a wrapper around the same C library) in your front-end, and if it fails, you'll know the app won't be able to handle it, right? Whatever the answer, the solution is probably more closely related to the problem than checking for losslessness.

Comment: PIL would be best. If PythonMagick is significantly easier then I can try to see if I can get it added.  As for the image formats, I only really need to handle those that can be opened with PIL - The image would be passed into scipy.misc.fromimage, providing a single input path for all images in the application (gifs for instance, I have noticed are formatted differently when opened in scipy directly). Lossless images are required in order to ensure that the data we are receiving has not been altered by compression (scientific purposes).

Comment: @GlenNelson you are approaching this incorrectly. Suppose someone submits a jpeg (which in its majority will be lossy), and then your program manages to return something that says: "lossy images are not supported". The user then happily proceeds to convert his jpeg to a png, and now your program accepts it. Why didn't you just convert his image to png and be done with it ? Why don't you convert every input image to a common lossless format before proceeding ?

Comment: @mmgp: Now that the OP has explained things, I think that's just a matter of proper messaging and documentation—make the JPEG warning explain that the data is already ruined, and converting it to PNG will not recover the missing information. If the user ignores that and does it anyway, that's their own problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I now understand things: You want to open the images via PIL. You want to reject lossy images because you're doing scientific processing of some kind that needs all that lost data because information that's unimportant for human visual processing is important for your algorithms.

PIL does not have any kind of interface at the top level to distinguish different types of compression. You *could* reach inside the image decoders and assume that anything that uses the "raw" decoder is lossless, but even if you wanted to do that, that's too limited—it'll rule out GIF, LZW-compressed TIFF, etc. along with JPEG, JPEG-compressed TIFF, etc.

Keep in mind that the real problem is here is messaging and documentation—managing user expectations. The check for lossy images is really just a heuristic, a way to catch the more obvious mistakes and remind the user what the requirements are. So, you don't need something perfect, but having something pretty good may be helpful anyway.

So, there are only a few options, none of them very good:

1. Hack up PIL's decoder source to retain the encoding information and pass it up to the top level. This is, obviously, going to take some non-trivial work, in 30 different importers, possibly involving C as well as Python, and it will result in a patch that you have to maintain against a (slowly-)evolving codebase—although of course you can always submit it upstream and hope that it makes it into future versions of PIL.
2. Dig into the decoders themselves to get the information at runtime. The only semi-standard thing you can really find is whether they use the raw decoder or the bit decoder, which isn't useful at all (many lossless formats will need the bit decoder), so you'll probably end up reading all 30 importers and writing a dozen or so pieces of code to extract information from them.
3. Use another library along with (or in place of) PIL. For example, while ImageMagick is definitely *not* significantly easier than PIL, it does have an API to tell you what type of compression an image file uses. Basically, if it's `UndefinedCompression` or `JPEGCompression` it's lossy, anything else, it's lossless. The major downside (besides needing to install two image libraries) is that there will be files that PIL can open but IM can't, and vice-versa, and multi-image files that PIL and IM handle differently, and so on.
4. Do what you're already doing. Read through the 30 importers to make a list of which are lossy and which are lossless. To handle cases like JPEG and TIFF that are sometimes lossless, you may want to write code that doesn't flat-out reject them, but instead gives a warning saying "These files may be lossy. Are you sure you want to import them?" (Or, alternatively, just offer an "I know what I'm doing" override for all lossy formats, and then just consider JPEG and TIFF lossy.)

For many use cases, I'd be very wary of going with #4, but for yours, it actually seems pretty reasonable. You're not trying to block lossy images because your code will crash, or for security reasons, or anything like that; you're just trying to warn people that they're going to waste a lot of time getting useless information if they submit a JPEG, right?

Comment: All these options are incorrect, sorry :/ These checks guarantee absolutely nothing. See that png image over there ? Maybe earlier in its life it was a jpeg, and maybe before that it was some raw data from a certain sensor. So it makes no sense to attempt to distinguish input based on that. The only sensible approach is adding the following (adjusted) line somewhere: "Dear user, every input received will be converted to format X before further processing."

Comment: @mmgp: That's why I said (in a comment to the question, though, not the answer) that it's really more a problem of messaging and documentation than programming. Maybe I should restructure the answer to say that as well.